# Group a list of list by nested size in R

Tags: r

I have a function that generates all subsets for a set, in a list of list.
I would like to group them by size, and have a list (indexed by the different sizes), of list (for the collection of subsets), of list (for the subset)

This is the code for generating the input (the list of all subsets)

```
library(plyr) 
library(ggplot2) 

all.subsets <- function(set) {   n <- length(set)   
                                 bin <- expand.grid(rlply(n, c(F, T)))
                                 mlply(bin, function(...) { set[c(...)] }) }

P3 <- all.subsets(c("a","b","c"))
```

Now I'd like to have instead of the whole list of subsets, a collection indexed by a size size, and that gives me a collection of all subsets of that size.

What would be the R way to perform this ?

Comment: Sorry it works. I deleted the comment...But this code is your input?..It is not clear the expected output.

Comment: ok I'll be more descriptive about the input/output

Comment: Does by `size` do you mean the `length` of element list? Maybe this can `lapply(P3,length)`  help.

Comment: with that, from a subset, I can get the size. I'd like to do the reverse : I give a size, I'd like the corresponding subsets

Answer (score 1):

To get all nested list of length equal to 1 you can do the following:

```
P3[lapply(P3,length) ==1]   ## get all elements with size equal to 1

$`2`
[1] "a"

$`3`
[1] "b"

$`5`
[1] "c"
```

Now, We can use this to group the nested lists by their lengths. We loop(`lapply`) over all unique  lengths, and we perform the above statement for each length :

```
lapply(unique(unlist(lapply(P3,length))),
       function(x) P3[lapply(P3,length) ==x] )
```

Comment: A bit like this... but for every possible sizes. in dotnet it would be like the IEnumerable.groupby operation, to which the length function would be supplied

Comment: Another application of lapply would do the trick though. although it feels there must be a better way.